# html or css to hide image after click

Tags: css, html

How do I make an image hidden after clicking anywhere inside a div and make it stay hidden until page refresh?

```
<style>
#containter:active img {display: none}
</style>

<div id="containter">
<img src="image.png">
</div>
```

This works but as soon as you move the mouse outside of the div, the image reappears. I know it supposed to do that, but how to make it remain hidden?

Comment: There are `:active` and `:focus` pseudo-classes available in css. If you want something else you can use an inline (or unobtrusive) function call such as `<div onclick="func()">` and set it via javascript.

Comment: I'm lousy with javascript so please correct me. It should be something like this? `onclick="img.style.visibility='hidden'"`

Comment: Something like `<div id="tempDiv" onclick="document.getElementById('tempDiv').style.visibility='hidden';">click me</div>` would work, but this is just an example, and not the way it should be done.

Comment: If you want it to stay hidden, then you have to use javascript.

Comment: Thanks everyone, you helped me. mgamba I used your inline code but instead of 'onclick' I'm using 'onmouseover'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an unobtrusive example for JS:

html:

```
<div id="tempDiv">click me</div>
```

js:

```
document.getElementById("tempDiv").onclick = function(e) {
  e.target.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

[and a jsfiddle for it](http://jsfiddle.net/xvxJJ/1/)

Answer (score 2):

A simple way of doing this is to wrap the item you want to hide on click in `<label>` and use a rule like

```
:checked + img {
    display: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kGDQq/1/

Comment: It's not semantic and also hidden radio buttons/checkboxes have poor support in older version of IE.

Answer (score 1):

In order to be semantically correct I suggest you use a JavaScript solution and don't try to do it with CSS/HTML hacks. The below method attaches a new click handler to all elements with the class `.hide-on-click`, simply add the class to any element you want to hide on click.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ycW5n/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="hide-on-click">Test 1</div>
<div class="hide-on-click">Test 2</div>
<div class="hide-on-click">Test 3</div>
<div class="hide-on-click">Test 4</div>
```

**JS**

```
(function () {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('hide-on-click');
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
            this.style.display = 'none';
        });
    }
})();
```

If you want the the space that the image took up not to collapse then you should use the `visibility` property.

```
this.style.visibility = 'hidden';
```